# SQL Most efficient way to split a column by values of another column

Tags: sql

Is there a better way to write this? I want to create a separate value column for each end_use_data_type. I have a bunch more 'end_use_data_type_id'

Thanks!

```
select coolingvalue, heatingvalue, ventvalue, miscvalue

from analysis a

join (SELECT aeup.value coolingvalue, analysis_id FROM annual_end_use_psft aeup 
WHERE aeup.end_use_data_type_id=1) cooling ON cooling.analysis_id=a.analysis_id

join (SELECT aeup.value heatingvalue, analysis_id FROM annual_end_use_psft aeup 
WHERE aeup.end_use_data_type_id=2) heating ON heating.analysis_id=a.analysis_id

join (SELECT aeup.value ventvalue, analysis_id FROM annual_end_use_psft aeup 
WHERE aeup.end_use_data_type_id=3) ventilation ON ventilation.analysis_id=a.analysis_id

join (SELECT aeup.value miscvalue, analysis_id FROM annual_end_use_psft aeup 
WHERE aeup.end_use_data_type_id=4) misc ON misc.analysis_id=a.analysis_id
```

Comment: One way can be using pivot: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: sorry I should have clarified - there are about 10 more columns I want to include in the select statement (including analysis_id, etc). Not sure if pivot will still work

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `join` and conditional aggregation:

```
select a.analysis_id,
       max(case when aeup.end_use_data_type_id = 1 then aeup.value end) as coolingvalue,
       max(case when aeup.end_use_data_type_id = 2 then aeup.value end) as heatingvalue, 
       max(case when aeup.end_use_data_type_id = 3 then aeup.value end) as ventvalue,
       max(case when aeup.end_use_data_type_id = 4 then aeup.value end) as miscvalue
from analysis a join
     annual_end_use_psft aeup
     on cooling.analysis_id = a.analysis_id and
        aeup.end_use_data_type_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by a.analysis_id;
```

Comment: Thanks gordon! I'm new to this so that worked (and clarifies things).